# Validar o conteúdo de uma célula do DataGridView

Tags: c#

Preciso de uma ajuda. Estou fazendo uma inserção de itens em um pedido, usando um *DataGridView*, nesse *DataGridView* tenho a coluna *código*, *descrição*, *lote* e *qtda*. Preciso validar a coluna *código*, fazendo com que se eu já tiver inserido o código 1, ele não insira novamente o código 1, ou seja, não posso ter itens repetidos na *grid*.

Segue o comando de inserção,
Método do botão `Inseri_Itens`

```
private void btn_inserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt_qtda.Text != "")
        {
            DGW_itens.Rows.Add(txt_codigo.Text, txt_produto.Text, cb_lote.Text, txt_fabric.Text, txt_qtda.Text, txt_numero.Text);

            txt_codigo.Text = "";
            txt_produto.Text = "";
            cb_lote.Items.Clear();
            cb_lote.Text = "";
            txt_fabric.Text = "";
            txt_qtda.Text = "0.00";
            txt_idsolicitacao.Text = "";
            btn_gravar.Enabled = true;
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não existem itens a serem incuidos, por favor verifique se o campo Qtda. esta preenchido!!!");
            return;

        }
    }
```

desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça uma iteração no seu DGW_itens e verifique se o código a ser inserido já existe no grid.

```
for (int i = 0; i < DGW_itens.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (txt_codigo.Text == DGW_itens.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
    {
      //Seu tratamento para código ja existente no grid
    }
    else
     {
     if (txt_qtda.Text != "")
        {
            DGW_itens.Rows.Add(txt_codigo.Text, txt_produto.Text, cb_lote.Text, txt_fabric.Text, txt_qtda.Text, txt_numero.Text);

            txt_codigo.Text = "";
            txt_produto.Text = "";
            cb_lote.Items.Clear();
            cb_lote.Text = "";
            txt_fabric.Text = "";
            txt_qtda.Text = "0.00";
            txt_idsolicitacao.Text = "";
            btn_gravar.Enabled = true;
        }
 else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não existem itens a serem incuidos, por favor verifique se o campo Qtda. esta preenchido!!!");
            return;

        }
   }
}
```

Solução em:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385597/preventing-duplicates-before-insert-in-datagridview

Comment: Vlw Andre deu certinho aqui muito obrigado.